# Can't find where my PATH is set in MacOS

Tags: bash, zsh, path, macos

For the record, I am running ZSH, FISH and GNU Bash on my system. I've checked every imaginable location and I cannot find where my $PATH variable is set:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin /usr/sbin **/Users/bobbi/opt/GNAT/2020/bin /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin** /usr/bin /bin /sbin
```

I've checked the following files and directories and probably others:

```
/etc/paths /etc/profile ~/.profile /etc/environment /etc/profile  ~/.bash_login ~/.bash_profile ~/.bashrc
```

I went through all of the path files and either deleted them or removed any lines where the path is set  with the exception of `/etc/paths`

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
```

I've read every post and I can't find a solution. I also tried running several which spits different results:

```
$/usr/libexec/path_helper
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/bobbi/opt/GNAT/2020/bin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin"; export PATH;

$ env -i bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.
```

I also did a grep and found this odd bit :

```
sh-3.2$ grep -rF --binary-files=without-match '/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin' / 2> /dev/null
/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20131216/etc/templates/TemplateProject/TemplateProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:              PATH = "$(PATH):/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin";
```

I even quit the terminal and restarted several times thinking it might be living in memory somewhere. Is there a script I can run where it will tell me exactly what file is responsible for setting the file?

Comment: It looks like you found the /usr/local/Cross.... file. Any particular value in the $PATH you are trying to chase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Xcode assigns its toolchain paths to the PATH variable. There are several places where Xcode modifies the path. The details are described in the following answer dated 10/22/20:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64478215/148298